# ffmpeg convert wma to mp3 in iOS

Tags: ios, ffmpeg

I want to convert a WMA file to MP3 in iOS. And I have successfully parse the WMA stream to `AVFrame` through learning the sample code here: http://www.inb.uni-luebeck.de/~boehme/using_libavcodec.html
But next I don't know how to convert the `AVFrame` to MP3 file, and I have tried the code like this but it does not work:

```
AVCodecContext *outCodecContext = NULL;
AVCodec *pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MP3);
if(pCodec == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "out avcodec_find_decoder error\n");
    exit(1);
}

AVCodecContext *pCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(pCodec);

if(pCodecCtx == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "out avcodec_alloc_context3 error\n");
    exit(1);
}

if(avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec, NULL) < 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "out avcodec_open error\n");
    exit(1);
}
outCodecContext = pCodecCtx;


do{
    AVPacket packet;
    if(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) < 0){
        break;
    }

    int got_frame_ptr;

    if(packet.stream_index==videoStream)
    {   
        avcodec_decode_audio4(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &got_frame_ptr, &packet);
        if(got_frame_ptr)
        {
            AVPacket outPacket;
            int out_got_packet_ptr;
            avcodec_encode_audio2(outCodecContext, &outPacket, pFrame, &out_got_packet_ptr);

            [finalData appendBytes:outPacket.data length:outPacket.size];
            NSLog(@"finalData len: %d", [finalData length]);
        }
    }
    av_free_packet(&packet);

}while(true);

NSString *svfp = [getAppDocumentDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"finalData"];
[finalData writeToFile:svfp atomically:YES];
```

I always get a message in the console:

```
[mp3 @ 0xa393200] nb_samples (12288) != frame_size (0) (avcodec_encode_audio2)
```

Any one can help? Thanks.

Comment: I may be wrong but I think for ffmpeg to create mp3 you need libLame, and there may be some licensing issues if this is a commercial product. So I guess the question is why do you need to convert to mp3 why not just play the wma. I'm assuming you using libmms or something to get the packets so you could convert to pcm and then use audioQueue api or AudioUnit api of ios to play the stream or file.https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/sampleDecoder/blob/master/AudioDecodeController.m

Comment: Thank you Michelle Cannon, you are guessing right, I'm working on a little app that play WMA stream using libmms + ffmpeg. And I'm stuck at the playing decoded AVFrame step. The example code seems not work and some files are missing. Do you have other examples? Thanks.

Comment: @MichelleCannon does mooncatventures-group still working? bcoz i have tried to implement it and not got successful to use any of the project that stream video in RTSP link.

Comment: As I explained before none of our examples are geared at wma conversion to mp3, there is no reason they can't be converted with a little work. the examples I give convert to PCM and play the audio via audio unit or audio queue api. If you are getting specific build errors please let us know via our Facebook group that I believe yo know about. common errors, new versions of Xcode require some small changes, remove armv7s arch and any entitlement plists that might be in projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can try swr_convert 
This code is for your reference

```
swr_convert(_swrContext,
                            outbuf,
                            _audioFrame->nb_samples * ratio,
                            (const uint8_t **)_audioFrame->data,
                            _audioFrame->nb_samples);
```